# Get only the file name from MS Access file browse

Tags: vba

I have the following VB code in MS Access:

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()
Dim dialog As FileDialog
Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    Me.Thumbnail = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With      
End Sub
```

I'd like to only have the file name returned instead of the full path name.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can't immediately return the file name from the dialog, it's relatively simple to isolate just the file name from the path that gets returned. So, once you get the path, you can do something like this to extract just the file name:

```
Dim fso as new FileSystemObject
Dim fileName As String
fileName = fso.GetFileName("C:\Temp\a_file.txt")
```

This will result in `fileName` containing "a_file.txt". Note that you must use the scripting library to access the `FileSystemObject`. To use it, add a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** (in the VBA Editor, go to: *Tools > References* and tick *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*).

For a pure VBA solution without any additional dependencies, you can create a function like this:

```
Public Function GetFilenameFromPath(ByVal strPath As String) As String
  If Right$(strPath, 1) <> "\" And Len(strPath) > 0 Then
    GetFilenameFromPath = GetFilenameFromPath(Left$(strPath, Len(strPath) - 1)) + Right$(strPath, 1)
  End If
End Function
```

Given a path, it'll return just the file name:

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = GetFilenameFromPath("C:\Temp\a_file.txt")
```

A third approach is to simply do:

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim fileName As String

strPath = "C:\Temp\a_file.txt"
fileName = Right$(strPath, Len(strPath) - InStrRev(strPath, "\"))
```

Finally, you can also use `Split` to get the file name from a path:

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim splitList As Variant

splitList = Split(strPath, "\")
fileName = splitList(UBound(splitList, 1))
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using one of the simplest solutions above, your final code would look something like this:

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()
  Dim dialog As FileDialog
  Dim filePath As String
  Dim fileName As String

  Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With dialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    filePath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    fileName = Right$(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
    'Me.Thumbnail = fileName
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to VBA.  I tried to implement your solution without success.  What should the the combined VBA code look like?