# VBA code for creating a checklist of items based on the table names in the database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to writing VBA codes in MS Access. I have created a form to import the excel files into Access but I need help on creating a checklist of the Tables/files I have uploaded in the form.
For example:

```
    condition if table name = "abc" is True then,
    display ABC1 
    if table name = "bac" is True then,
    display ABC2
    else " "
    end if
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I'm sorry it is unclear what you are asking. Why a VBA checklist? I suggest creating a table that holds information on excel sheets. Then you could just do a checkbox for "imported yes/no". Comparing the filenames to the table names isn't a good idea.

Comment: let me try to make the question a little more clear. I have created a form to import Excel files into the Access database. But now I am thinking is it possible to provide a list of files the user has uploaded every time s/he imports? The table does not need to be displayed in the form but the name should.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear so my apologies if I answer the wrong question.  A common problem Is importing Data that was recorded in Excel into an Access database.    So access provides a wizard.  On the ribbon click external Data then new data source then file then Excel.  Work your way through the Wizard.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958

[image]

tip when building the database you can get a jumpstart by importing to a new table but otherwise select append to your current table.  Make and save an import query for each table you are importing from Excel.

tip 2: access and Excel can talk to each other but in access you have to enable the feature.  Here is a link for how to do that since usually you would want to clear the excel tables after importing their data.  If the wizard doesn't work because the Excel tables are not well formed you can grab the data cell by cell after you enable communication.

https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/open-excel-file/

Assuming you now have the appropriate access tables make a new blank form and drag each table onto the forms details section.  Access will then create subforms for each table.  Stack the subforms on top of each other.  In this way if only 1 subform is visible they all appear at the same place. Next add a listbox and a button to the form header section.

[image]

I also created a table to keep track of the excel table names and when they were last imported.

[image]

Here is the code that hooks everything together:

```
Option Compare Database

Private OriginalListboxColor As Long


Private Sub cmdImportDatafromExcelTable_Click()
'show the appropriate table and import any data in the appropriate excel table
Dim AppropriateUniformsTableID As Integer: AppropriateUniformsTableID = 1
Dim OfficersTableID As Integer: OfficersTableID = 2
If lstExcelTableNames = AppropriateUniformsTableID Then
Me.Officers_subform.Visible = False
Me.AppropriateUniforms_subform.Visible = True
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ("LoadUniformData")
UpdateExcelTableNamesLastImportedOn (AppropriateUniformsTableID)
ChangeListboxColorifInvalidLastImportedOn

Else
Me.AppropriateUniforms_subform.Visible = False
Me.Officers_subform.Visible = True
DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ("LoadOfficerData")
UpdateExcelTableNamesLastImportedOn (OfficersTableID)
ChangeListboxColorifInvalidLastImportedOn
End If
Me.Refresh 'update data from recordsource
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateExcelTableNamesLastImportedOn(TableID As Integer)
Dim db As Database
Dim sqlstring As String
Set db = CurrentDb
sqlstring = "UPDATE ExcelTableNames SET LastImportedOn = #" & Now() & "# WHERE ID = " & TableID
db.Execute sqlstring
Set db = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
OriginalListboxColor = Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderColor
ChangeListboxColorifInvalidLastImportedOn
End Sub

Private Sub ChangeListboxColorifInvalidLastImportedOn()
If DateDiff("d", DMin("LastImportedOn", "ExcelTableNames"), Now()) > 2 Then
Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderColor = vbRed
Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderWidth = 2
Else
Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderColor = OriginalListboxColor
Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderWidth = 1
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'OriginalListboxColor = Me.lstExcelTableNames.BorderColor
'ChangeListboxColorifInvalidLastImportedOn
End Sub
```

When you hit the button the form imports data from the selected excel table and updates when the form was last imported.  if any table hasn't been imported in 2 days the listbox border is turned red.  I couldn't turn the listbox item red with the default listbox control but you can do other things.  The date last loaded was my best guess for the criteria you would want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you. But let me try to make the question a little more clear. I have created a form to import Excel files into the Access database. But now I am thinking is it possible to provide a list of files the user has uploaded every time s/he imports? The table does not need to be displayed in the form but the name should be.

Comment: what you need is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006283/get-only-the-file-name-from-ms-access-file-browse